# InputField Conditional Font Styling

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, style, pageblocksection

I have a requirement to conditionally style the font for a single inputfield based on the User's profile, however, below statement does not appear to be rendering properly.  Is this possible using native Visualforce 'style' function?

```
<apex:inputField value="{!PartnershipRequest__c.OverallStatus__c}" style="{$Profile.Name!='System Administrator',color:gray}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

What you need to fix:

- You are missing the `IF` function entirely
- You are missing quotes around your `value_if_true`
- You are missing `value_if_false` entirely
- You are missing the bang (`!`) in your merge syntax

  - Correct syntax is `{!...}`, not `{...}`

**Incorrect:**

```
"{$Profile.Name!='System Administrator',color:gray}"
```

**Correct:**

```
"{!IF($Profile.Name!='System Administrator','color:gray', ''}"
```

Note that generally, using `class` attributes is preferable to inline styling (`styleClass` for Visualforce components such as `<apex:inputField>`).

Comment: Thanks Adrian.  Is the syntax exactly the same for outputField?

Comment: The syntax for the `IF` function never changes...